# Use client certificate from Azure Website instance

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Website instance that needs to connect **out** to a WCF service running elsewhere that is secured using a client certificate.

`Client -> Azure Website (MVC Controller) -> WCF Service (Not Azure) that requires Client Certificate`

I have been supplied a CER file that when installed locally allows my website to connect to the WCF service.  How do I install/make available this certificate available on the Azure Website?

All the documentation I've found when researching this is all about securing a WCF service when running in Azure, and requires the installation of PFX files with passwords.  I'm trying to do the opposite and connect outbound from an Azure Website to a third party WCF service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Add the following Application Setting:

- App Setting name: `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`
- Value: `*` or `{CERT_THUMBPRINT}`

You can then grab the certificate from `My` store:

```cs
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 // Replace below with yourcert's thumbprint
                                 "E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870”,
                                 false);
```

Now, i don't think you'll be able to upload a `.cer`.
`.pfx` seems to be the only accepted format in App Service.

[image: error_uploading_cer]

Or just load it from the disk if there's no private key to worry about.
This lets you load `.cer` as well (DER works, probably Base64 too):

```cs
// The path to the certificate.
string Certificate = @"d:\home\site\cert.cer";

// Load the certificate into an X509Certificate object.
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);

// Print to console
string result = cert.ToString(true);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Works just fine in App Service (here it is running in the [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)):

[image: loadCert_Kudu_screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, put the .cer file into App_Data, loaded it using the X509Certificate2 constructor and used it with my WCF client.  I did have to set CertificateValidationMode to none as it wasn't installed, but it's now deployed and working.