# How to work with X509Certificate2 and pfx file?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a web application that needs a physical address of pfx file and use it for signing/encrypting data and everything works fine.

I want to upload the code on Azure app service with the least changes in the code. How do I do it? can I specify the pfx path somehow instead of physical address?

What shall I do?

I've found other sources like this:
[Use client certificate from Azure Website instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065150/use-client-certificate-from-azure-website-instance)

But all of them rely on uploading the certificate into Azure.

### More info

In my code I am using this override of X509Certificate2:

```
 X509Certificate2(string filename)
```

Which works perfectly fine with a physical address like

```
C:\myfile.pfx
==>  X509Certificate2("myfile.pfx")
```

However, when I try it with the relative address on my website, it fails.

```
X509Certificate2("/files/myfile.pfx") // fails
```

Comment: What do you mean by the physical address of a pfx file?

Comment: @bartonjs X509Certificate2(filename) is one of the overloads of the X509Certificate2 which has been used in my code. In my localdev I can give it an address like c:\file.pfx but when I've tried it with a relative address on my website it failed. something like "/file.pfx"

Comment: _"when I've tried it with a relative address on my website it failed"_ - can you download the file and [use the contructor that takes a byte array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148418(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `/files/myfile.pfx` is an *absolute* path (for POSIX paths), and is either being interpreted as gibberish, or `[current drive]\files\myfile.pfx`. A *physical address* would be something like the sector on disk where the contents actually live.  If you want an actual *relative* address for your second example, start it with `.` (e.g. `./files/myfile.pfx`), or just remove the leading slash.  (Though like @stuartd suggested, try `File.Read` and using the `byte[]`-based ctor.)